# my query to produce results based on date range is returning null. Any ideas why?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the following query:

```
select * 
  from myTable 
 where TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( transdate,'DD-MM-YY'),'MM/DD/YYYY')) Between
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-13','DD-MM-YY'),'MM/DD/YYYY')) AND 
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('10-07-13','DD-MM-YY'),'MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

is not getting any records from the db.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

`transdate` is in the format of `'dd-mm-yy'`.

My query to produce results based on date range is returning null. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is it possible for transdate to be NULL?

Comment: Is `transdate` a `date`?  Or is it a `varchar2`?  Is the year in the `varchar2` 2 or 4 digits (and why would anyone be using 2-digit years after all the fun we had with Y2K not so long ago)?

Comment: @RickS, no, transdate is not null. I queried the db first and determined that there are several transdate values that fall within the specified date range.

Justin, I am new to Oracle but in sql server, that format will not be of date variety. It will be varchar but not real sure with Oracle.

Your point about Y2K is a great one. I have no idea why users are allowed to enter dates in that format.

Comment: you should not convert the dates back to strings. Why do you do that? And what *datatype* is `transdate` if it's declared as `DATE` then you can get rid of all the `to_date()`/`to_char()` completely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix your problem by using proper date formats for comparing dates as strings:

```
 select * 
 from myTable 
 where TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( transdate,'DD-MM-YY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) Between
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-13','DD-MM-YY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND 
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('10-07-13','DD-MM-YY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

But you should really just be doing:

```
select *
from myTable
where trunc(transdate) between to_date('2013-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2013-07-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Or, better yet:

```
select *
from myTable
where transdate >= to_date('2013-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
      transdate < to_date('2013-07-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```